# No detection of UDP packets using Raw Sockets

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, networking

I'm struggling with a Raw Sockets program I'm putting together right now. I'm developing on Ubuntu 16.04 and using the sys/sockets.h file. My Ubuntu box is a virtual machine which is NAT routed (VMWare) to my physical network through my physical Windows 10 PC.

I've written the following code and run my program as root (to prevent Raw socket permissions errors). I receive no errors code from the socket(), setsockopt(), or sendto() commands. Sendto() returns 32, implying that a UDP packet is being sent. However, Wireshark seems to show no evidence that this packet is ever released onto the network.

```
int main(){
    cout << "UDP Packet Sender\n";
    PacketArgs* p_args = new PacketArgs;
    p_args->setDestIP("192.168.204.1");
    p_args->setSrcIP("192.168.204.128");
    p_args->setDestPort(500);
    p_args->setSrcPort(500);
    p_args->setProtocol(17);
    p_args->setPacketLength(sizeof(struct ip_header)+ sizeof(struct udp_header));

    UDPArgs* udp_args = new UDPArgs;
    udp_args->setSrcPort(500);
    udp_args->setDestPort(500);
    udp_args->setLength(htons(sizeof(udp_header)));

    UDPPacket* packet = new UDPPacket(p_args,udp_args);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){    
         packet->sendPacket();
    }
}
```

^^ main.cpp

```
Packet::Packet(PacketArgs* args){
    buffer = new char[PCKT_LENGTH];
    std::memset(buffer, 0, PCKT_LENGTH);
    m_packet = (ip_header*)buffer;
    m_packet->iph_ihl = 5;
    m_packet->iph_ver = 4;
    m_packet->iph_tos = 16;
    m_packet->iph_len = args->getPacketLength();
    m_packet->iph_ident = htons(54321);
    m_packet->iph_ttl = 64;
    m_packet->iph_protocol = args->getProtocol();
    m_packet->iph_sourceip = args->getSrcIP();
    m_packet->iph_destip = args->getDestIP();

}

unsigned short Packet::calculateChecksum(size_t* buf, int nwords){
    unsigned long sum;
    for(sum=0; nwords>0; nwords--)
        sum += *buf++;
    sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum &0xffff);
    sum += (sum >> 16);
    return (unsigned short) (~sum);
}
```

^^ Packet.cpp

```
UDPPacket::UDPPacket(PacketArgs* p_args, UDPArgs* udp_args): Packet(p_args){
    m_udp = (struct udp_header*)(buffer + sizeof(struct ip_header));
    m_udp->udph_srcport = udp_args->getDestPort();
    m_udp->udph_destport = udp_args->getSrcPort();
    m_udp->udph_len = htons(sizeof(struct udp_header));
    m_packet->iph_checksum = calculateChecksum((size_t*)&m_packet, sizeof(struct ip_header) + sizeof(struct udp_header));
}

int UDPPacket::sendPacket(){
    int sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP);

    struct sockaddr_in src, dest;   
    src.sin_family = AF_INET;
    dest.sin_family = AF_INET;

    src.sin_port = htons(m_udp->udph_srcport);
    dest.sin_port = htons(m_udp->udph_destport);
    src.sin_addr.s_addr = m_packet->iph_sourceip;
    dest.sin_addr.s_addr = m_packet->iph_destip;

    int one = 1;
    const int* val = &one;

    int sso = setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, val, sizeof(one));

    std::cout << "sso is: " << sso << std::endl << "sd is: " << sd << std::endl;

    int st = sendto(sd,buffer,m_packet->iph_len,0,(struct sockaddr*)&src, sizeof(src));

    std::cout << "st is: " << st << std::endl;

}
```

^^ UDPPacket.cpp

Part of what is confusing me is that even listening with Wireshark on the Ubuntu machine yields no results, so it would seem that the packet never actually leaves the interface at all. Does anyone have any advice for this?

Comment: you need to fill in the ethernet header as well and set a MAC addr of outg IF on a socket. take a look: https://gist.github.com/austinmarton/1922600

Comment: Please try a bridged VM network instead of NAT, that solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that running the VM network adaptor in NAT mode was causing the issue. Once I switched to bridge everything was all good.